# spring-boot MyBatisBatchItemWriter Cannot change the ExecutorType when there is an existing transaction

Tags: spring-boot

I'm use spring boot and mybatis MyBatisBatchItemWriter.
Using demo to write data(mysql) to the database when no problem.
but Used in the my project 
`org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: Cannot change the ExecutorType when there is an existing transaction
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils.getSqlSession(SqlSessionUtils.java:91) ~[mybatis-spring-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:353) ~[mybatis-spring-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]`

this my demo:

```
 @Bean
public MyBatisBatchItemWriter<Hfbank> writer() {
    MyBatisBatchItemWriter<Hfbank> writer = new MyBatisBatchItemWriter<Hfbank>();
    writer.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
    String statementId = "com.springboot.dao.HfbankDao.insertSelective";
    writer.setStatementId(statementId);
    CompositeItemWriter compositeItemWriter  = new CompositeItemWriter();
     List delegates = new ArrayList();
     delegates.add(writer);
     compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(delegates);
     writer.setAssertUpdates(false);
    return writer;
}
```

this my MyBatisBatchItemWriter:

```
@Bean
 @StepScope
public MyBatisBatchItemWriter<ChannelDataInfo> writer(@Value("#{jobParameters[channelid]}")  Long channelid) {
    MyBatisBatchItemWriter<ChannelDataInfo> writer = new MyBatisBatchItemWriter<ChannelDataInfo>();
    SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH);

    writer.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
    String statementId = "com.kaigejava.fundcheck.repository.ChannelDataInfoRepository.insertSelective";

    writer.setStatementId(statementId);
    CompositeItemWriter compositeItemWriter  = new CompositeItemWriter();
     List delegates = new ArrayList();
     delegates.add(writer);
     compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(delegates);
     writer.setAssertUpdates(false);
    return writer;
}
```

why demo ok but  my project has error?

Answer (score 0):

Because it sais it: you can't change the executor type inside the transaction.

it looks like you've tried to batch-write something as the part of more broad transaction that includes other SQL operations, but that transaction was started with SIMPLE (default) or REUSE executor type.

It's obvious, that batch-write requires BATCH executor type, though once the transaction started, it's executor type can not be changed. So, perform your batch operations in separate transaction, or run nested transaction, if your RDBMS allows it.